# Magento ensure module config is loaded last

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, configuration

Is there a way to ensure that a module and its config xml is loaded last in Magento, or at least after a specific other module?

I want to avoid using the `<depends>` tag because it may not be 100% that the module i want my configuration loaded after will be installed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From what I am reading, the only way to do this is by the depends tag, even if you made your module name ZZZ... The module list is re-ordered after being fetched based on dependencies...

> The function Mage_Core_Model_Config::_loadDeclaredModules scans the
>   directory etc/modules and loads XML files located there. These files
>   contain module declarations. Before loading their contents, the system
>   arranges them into a specific order. The first file in this list is
>   Mage_All.xml. The modules declared in this file comprise the essential
>   core functionality of Magento. Next in line are the declaration files
>   whose names begin with Mage_. The modules declared there are a part of
>   the Magento core as well, but often depend on the modules from the
>   Mage_All.xml file and thus must be loaded after those. The rest of the
>   list are declarations of third party modules: community modules and
>   your local extensions. Once the list is compiled, Magento fetches the
>   files in the order they are listed and loads their contents into an
>   object of type Mage_Core_Model_Config_Base – the application
>   configuration object, which Magento queries whenever a configuration
>   entry is requested. The loaded configuration must be ordered once more
>   – this time according to module dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Though Jeffrey L. Roberts' answer is Magento-1 specific in details, the same answer applies for Magento 2. Without declaring a dependency (in the `<sequence>` element), one **cannot alter the order of Modules' loading** in Magento 1 or Magento 2.

One would have to address the specific reason for ensuring that their module is loaded after another module on a case-by-case basis. Th PHP function `class_exists()` is often useful for this.